# How do I disable emails from job alerts?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm still receiving emails with subject "New jobs on Stack Overflow" from *do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com*. At the bottom of them, I see:

> You're receiving this email because you created a job alert on Stack Overflow
>   *Manage job alerts*

But when I click on *Manage job alerts*, I have no active email alerts. I don't know how to stop receiving these emails.

I asked for these emails before the migration from Stack Overflow Jobs to Stack Exchange, so maybe an old version of a job alert is still active, but I can't see it in the new interface. I don't know.

Comment: A second account would be the simplest explanation, any chance of that?

Comment: so.. you have the right to remain silent..

Comment: I can't find another account associated with your current email address. What address was the email sent to? Feel free to forward the email to me at dward at stackoverflow.com

Comment: Happened to me too, checking the actual address revealed it was sent to "myaddress+sock-address@gmail.com" meaning one of my sock accounts, using the "+" gmail trick. (So expected behavior.)

Comment: Maybe relevant note, do-not-reply email adresses are illegal to use to send to people located in the Netherlands. It's mandated by law that there is a person behind it to handle any complaints/unsubscriptions sent by reply.

Comment: @Tschallacka Off-topic curiosity: has the law ever been used in anger?

Comment: brb moving to Netherlands

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Not much point as evidently it's not enforced very well ;)